# Postman 'swapping the old app with new one' and corrupting itself automatically

Tags: postman

I'm on a fresh installation of Linux Mint 20. I have downloaded the latest Postman (postman-9.12.2-linux-x64.tar.gz), unzipped it and I can start it and use it with no problems.

However after I reboot my PC (sometimes it takes two reboots) Postman's "app" folder gets  renamed to "Postman-1644591908495-old". The link to executable app/postman stops working (as there is no such file). The whole folder structure seems to be messed up at this point and I can't even locate the executable. As a result, I cannot start Postman. I need to delete everything, unzip from the package and then it runs again until 1-2 restarts when it corrupts itself again.

After it gets corrupted there is a log.txt file with this content:

```
2022/02/11 16:06:45:676 Postman-1644591908495 Swapping the old app with new one
2022/02/11 16:06:45:680 Postman-1644591908495 Swapping done
2022/02/11 16:06:45:682 Postman-1644591908495 Swapping the old app with new one
2022/02/11 16:06:45:689 Postman-1644591908495 Parent process is alive, killing it now
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with Postman failing to complete the update process. I solved the problem by selecting Help->Check for Updates. It found a newer version, I updated, and the problem was gone.